# Enum set to default value in Equals()

Tags: vb.net

I got this code:

```
Imports System.Collections.Generic

Public Class Part
    Implements IEqualityComparer(Of Part)

    Public Property _comparisonType As EqualsComparmission

    Public Sub New(ComparisonType As EqualsComparmission)
        Me._comparisonType = ComparisonType
    End Sub

    Public Sub New()
    End Sub

    Public Property PartName() As String
    Public Property PartId() As Integer

    Public Overrides Function ToString() As String
        Return "ID: " & PartId & "   Name: " & PartName
    End Function


    Public Function Equals12222(x As Part, y As Part) As Boolean Implements System.Collections.Generic.IEqualityComparer(Of Part).Equals
        If x Is Nothing AndAlso y Is Nothing Then Return True
        If x Is Nothing OrElse y Is Nothing Then Return False

        Select Case _comparisonType
            Case EqualsComparmission.PartId
                Return x.PartId = y.PartId
            Case EqualsComparmission.PartName
                Return String.Equals(x.PartName, y.PartName)
            Case EqualsComparmission.PartId_and_PartName
                Return x.PartId = y.PartId AndAlso String.Equals(x.PartName, y.PartName)
            Case Else
                Throw New NotSupportedException("Unknown comparison type for parts: " & _comparisonType.ToString())
        End Select
    End Function

    Public Overrides Function Equals(obj As Object) As Boolean
        If obj Is Nothing Then
            Return False
        End If
        Dim objAsPart As Part = TryCast(obj, Part)
        Dim result As Boolean = False

        Select Case _comparisonType
            Case EqualsComparmission.PartId
                result = Me.PartId.Equals(objAsPart.PartId)
            Case EqualsComparmission.PartName
                result = Me.PartName.Equals(objAsPart.PartName)
            Case EqualsComparmission.PartId_and_PartName
                result = Me.PartId.Equals(objAsPart.PartId) And Me.PartName.Equals(objAsPart.PartName)
            Case Else
                Throw New NotSupportedException("Unknown comparison type for parts: " & _comparisonType.ToString())
        End Select

        Return result
    End Function

End Class


Public Enum EqualsComparmission

    PartId
    PartName
    PartId_and_PartName

End Enum
```

This is how i am removing something from list if this exists:

```
parts.Remove(New Part(EqualsComparmission.PartId_and_PartName) With { _
         .PartId = 11, _
         .PartName = "ala" _
    })
```

problem is when code hits Equals method it always picking first enum default value so :

```
Select Case _comparisonType
         Case EqualsComparmission.PartId
              result = Me.PartId.Equals(objAsPart.PartId)
```

**I debugged the code line by line also with watch.**

First it goes to:

```
Public Sub New(ComparisonType As EqualsComparmission)
        Me._comparisonType = ComparisonType
    End Sub
```

and correctly set the value of

```
Public Property _comparisonType As EqualsComparmission
```

to

```
EqualsComparmission.PartId_and_PartName
```

then debugger goes back to line again:

```
parts.Remove(New Part(EqualsComparmission.PartId_and_PartName) With { _
       .PartId = 11, _
       .PartName = "ala" _
  })
```

**and then it goes directly to Equals and now the property is equal to PartId !!??**

Comment: Try putting a breakpoint in the Sub New() that takes no parameters.  I'm guessing something is constructing a new instance.

Comment: i was guessing it so - Sub New is not hit in this case i checked already.

Comment: All your parts are constructed as `EqualsComparmission.PartId` (the default).  Only the one in the Remove() method uses a different one and *his* `Equals` method isnt the one used.  The ones in the list are used and they are all PartID

Comment: can you explain in more details cant get it.

Comment: the Remove is going to iterate the list to find the one which matches the new one passed: `If plist(0).Equals(newPart) then...` the problem is that all the ones in the list are `PartID`. `newPart` has `PartId_and_PartName` but his Equals is not used

Comment: where in code i should make a change then? Should i have other Equals or?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All the items in your list, using the simple ctor are set for `PartId` compare.  Your test code:

```
parts.Remove(New Part(EqualsComparmission.PartId_and_PartName) With { _
       .PartId = 11, _
       .PartName = "ala" _
  })
```

The list is going to be iterated to find a match resulting in:

```
If parts(n).Equals(newPart) Then
```

That Part/Item created in the method is an argument, so it is the RHS.  All the list items are set as `PartID` so that is what is used to compare.  One way to fix it is how you call it:

```
Dim plist As New List(Of Part)
plist.Add(New Part With {.PartId = 42, .PartName = "screw"})
plist.Add(New Part With {.PartId = 14, .PartName = "nail"})

Dim testP As New Part(EqualsComparmission.PartId_and_PartName) With {
 .PartId = 42,
 .PartName = "screw"
     }

For n As Integer = plist.Count - 1 To 0 Step -1
    If testP.Equals(plist(n)) Then        ' using Equals from the Temp Part
        plist.RemoveAt(n)
        ' maybe Exit For if you expect only one
    End If
Next
```

You could also overload Equals:

```
Public Overloads Function Equals(obj As Object, 
          compareType As EqualsComparmission) As Boolean
...
If testP.Equals(plist(0), EqualsComparmission.PartId_and_PartName) Then
```

This would allow you to specify the compare method when it is invoked, but that wont allow you to use it like you were.  Your List is invoking `Equals` method on the list items, and it will use the `Equals(obj As Object)` version.

Comment: to be honest i still cant get that but this works, anyway could it be done over my Part class? My thinking is Equals which is already located in my Part class are the one for specific Part object and its hitted. Cant get what ther Equals you talking about :) :(.

Comment: I am not sure I would include the compareType in the class - that seems more likely to be determined at the time you perform the compare (ie as an arg).  Otherwise, that IS your Part class - I just copied to run it and confirm what I thought was wrong.

Comment: `parts(0)` has an Equals.  So does the temp one you create in the Remove() method.  You want the temp one used, but it is not, the one on `parts(0), parts(1) etc` is used and those are all `PartId`

Comment: i think the extension method will be much better what do you think as suggested i put it as an answer lets check

Comment: I think it is so specific in nature to that class, that I would leave it as a method.  The extension is kind of nice for acting on the list, but for that level of management, I would use a collection class instead of a List<T> variable.

Comment: anyway what do you use - your solution, the extension method one or maybe this one?:  Dim deleted As Integer = parts.RemoveAll(Function(x) x.PartName = "something")

Comment: If you implement a collection class to manage the list for you, you can get rid of all that Equals code and have the collection class implement it for you as well as receive params for type of compare

Comment: do you have any example of what you are saying, because i am just new in this kind of playing with list and so on. Just give me example or link i would appreciate that.

Comment: [This CodeProject article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/718006/Enhanced-CollectionEditor-Framework) is about collection editors, but uses zillions of collection classes in the demo (almost all the main types there are)

Comment: funnt thing was also i put IEnumerator inside Part class and implemented GetEnumerator inside. Strange thing was when debug over foreach it was not riched GetEnumerator inside Part.. Do you know why ?